# Centos release 6.4 - files transferred via samba are corrupted

Tags: linux, centos, samba

I routinely transfer files to remote linux machines via samba. On one particular machine, every file that I transfer becomes corrupted. For example, the example file 'test.txt':

```
testing testing
```

becomes:

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

As you probably notice, each character is turning into a null value. Obviously this is a problem. I'm not sure if the problem is samba or not, but below is the essentials of /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[global]
        workgroup = <groupname>
        realm = <realmname.com>
        security = ADS
        kerberos method = system keytab
        wins support = no
        password server = <servername>
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
        encrypt passwords = yes
        local master = no
        preferred master = no
        netbios name = <netbiosname>

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        browseable = Yes
        read only = No
        public = yes
        inherit acls = Yes
```

The issue happens when trying to copy from windows to the 'homes' directory. Has anyone had this same problem? Any solutions?

Comment: Is your situation at all similar to this one? http://superuser.com/questions/371122/cifs-over-anyconnect-mac-to-linux-corrupt-files

Comment: No, sorry - I don't use a vpn. Also, the corruption here seems to be different from that situation.